# Java - How to print chars inbewteen two seleted chars by the user?

Tags: java, char

This program is supposed to take two char values from the user and number of char values per line they want to display. Then output the char values in between the two char values that the user inputted and respective chars per line.
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayCharactersInBetween {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ch1, ch2;
        int charsPerLine;
        System.out.print("Between what two characters do you wish to print: ");
        ch1 = console.next();
        ch2 = console.next();
        System.out.print("And how many chars per line: ");
        charsPerLine = console.nextInt();
        printChars(ch1.charAt(0), ch2.charAt(0), charsPerLine);
        console.close();
    }

    public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int charsPerLine) {
        int difference = (int)(ch2 - ch1);
        for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
            System.out.print(++ch1 + " ");
            if (ch1 == ch2)
                break;
            if (i % charsPerLine == 0)
                System.out.print(++ch1 + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

For example I choose a and z. I also choose 4 as the number per lines. I first do not understand why the first line only has two letters and the following few have 5 letters.

This is my output:

```
b c

d e f g h

i j k l m

n o p q r

s t u v w

x y z
```

Comment: First line has 2 letters because on first round `b` is printed, then `0 % 5 == 0` and thus it prints `c` and a line break on the second `if` clause.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks to all for your insights. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try these modifications, also think about the logic of the problem. It's easier than you thought:

**Code**:

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int charsPerLine)
{
    int difference = (int) (ch2 - ch1);

    for (int i = 1; i < difference; i++) { // Adjust the range, start in 1 so it doesn't print another line when i == 0
        System.out.print(++ch1 + " ");
        if (i % charsPerLine == 0) { // Just check if (i % 4 == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't need to check if `ch1 == ch2` because the `for` statement will "do" it for you.

**Output:**

```
b c d e 
f g h i 
j k l m 
n o p q 
r s t u 
v w x y
```

This prints all characters **between** `a` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

`i` should be `(i + 1)` and I changed the `if` to an `if/else`. It works now

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int charsPerLine) {
    int difference = (int) (ch2 - ch1);
    for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++) {

        if (ch1 == ch2) {
            break;
        }
        if ((i + 1) % charsPerLine == 0) {
            System.out.print(ch1++ + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print(ch1++ + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Input

```
a z 4
```

Output

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
q r s t
u v w x
y
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I want to clarify it: You want to print specified numbers of characters per line from spot X to spot Y (x and y is interval between letters?

If So ,the algorithm can be:

```
int  printAmount = 3;
  char letter1='a';
  char letter3='z';
  char letter2=(char) ((int)letter1+printAmount-1);

  for(letter1='a';letter1<=letter3;letter1++){
      System.out.print(letter1);
      if(letter1==letter2){
          System.out.println();
          letter2+=printAmount;
      }

  }
```

This is not very elegant way, but it works (if I understand correctly your purpose). Also it is only an algorithm, if you want, you can adapt it in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop can be simplified using the fact that char is converted to int:

```
for (int c = ch1 + 1; c < ch2; c++)
    System.out.print((char) c + ((c - ch1)%charsPerLine == 0 ? "\n":" "));
```

---

***Output*** ([view full code here](http://ideone.com/dIYUoV)):

```
b c d e f
g h i j k
l m n o p
q r s t u
v w x y
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are there only 2 chars on the first line ? - because in the first iteration i = 0 and 0 % 0 = 0, this means that in the first iteration you print b c and a new line character.

You are also printing z at the end  (is that what you want?). Try this (it doesn't print z, if you need z then just replace < by <=) :

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int charsPerLine) {
    int difference = (int)(ch2 - ch1);
    ch1++;
    for (int i = 1; i < difference; i++) {
        System.out.print(ch1++ + " ");
        if (i % charsPerLine == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to learn how to use debugging in java (it is very easy with eclipse or any other IDE) - it is very easy to find mistakes like this one.